# How to asign user www-data write permision to user folder but not user to other users folder?

Tags: linux, apache, server, debian, file-permissions

I'm trying to setup a multiuser server... I need the www-data user have read/write/execute permissions to all users folders so webs can load ok.
But I don't wont users to get access the others users folders, so I put users folders to 700.

```
chmod -R 700 /home/username
usermod -a -G username www-data
```

If I check members of the user_group it show www-data as members of the group

```
#members username
#username www-data
```

But when I try to access the web I get permission error

```
[core:error] [pid 16069] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:37758] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/username/file') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Giving 775 permission works ok, but other user can read data

Please advise
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set it up this way:

```
rwxr-x--- (750)   /home/user1     Owner: user1    Group: user1
rwxr-x--- (750)   /home/user2     Owner: user2    Group: user2
[...]
```

And make user www-data (I assume this is the user which runs your Apache) a member of groups user1, user2, ...  This way, www-data can read and access the home directories of users.  But users do not see the other user's files.

Also, users do not need to be members of group www-data if you do this.

*If you really must*, you could put 770 but I do not see what business Apache has to be able to write in user directories.  A system setup like this for my user would be a major flag and I would question the admin about it (and frankly I would remove the write permission on my group for sure).  Obviously, YMMV, but the reason better be a great one.

Comment: I need 770 becouse www-data user need to write files load from the web, file upload mostly.
But I asign permission as you said, before and after posting this topic and I get the same error, www-data user doesnt have read perm.
I cant login as www-data to check if from command line have, becouse for security issues I read www-data should have login permission

Comment: It is not just the permissions, group ownership must be setup as well.  As for your login on user www-data, the admins and security guys I know would say to not allow login.  Instead they would say to login with your user and switch to the application user as required.  For the 77 I use an upload directory that can only be uploaded to.  This way I separate the uploads with the site files.

Comment: Ah yes and make sure www-data can traverse /home first (x permission).